# Cannot register highlighting rule for XML

Tags: xml, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1.2

I'm running a XML analisys on my code using SonarQube 5.1.2 but getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot register highlighting rule for characters from 8136 to 8139 as it overlaps at least one existing rule
  at org.sonar.batch.highlighting.SyntaxHighlightingDataBuilder.checkOverlappingBoudaries(SyntaxHighlightingDataBuilder.java:77)
  at org.sonar.batch.highlighting.SyntaxHighlightingDataBuilder.build(SyntaxHighlightingDataBuilder.java:64)
  at org.sonar.batch.source.DefaultHighlightable$DefaultHighlightingBuilder.done(DefaultHighlightable.java:79)
  at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.saveSyntaxHighlighting(XmlSensor.java:118)
  at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.runChecks(XmlSensor.java:102)
35 more
```

I'm using SonarQube 5.1.2 and the XML plugin version is 1.4.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: You also raised that problem on the google group. Please don't cross post.